# Decision between an user-based and item-based filter

Tags: recommender-system

I'm working on an algorithm to generate recommendations for a platform where you can review restaurants. So the database exists of 3 tables, 'Users', 'Restaurants' and 'Reviews'. Reviews have a rating of 1-5. Each restaurant can have multiple reviews, and users can have multiple reviews. A review can only have 1 user and 1 restaurant.

**First I'll explain my current research/conclusions**

I have implemented most of an user-based system, but I'm encountering several issues that come from this way of generating recommendations.

First of all, the data sparsity issue, because there is a possibility that users have a few reviews on very different restaurants, it's very difficult to determine a correlation between users.

Second I have encountered the cold-start problem. Before being able to calculate a correlation between users, you'll need around 4 reviews per review on exactly the same restaurants.
*I have found a 'solution' for this by using a content-based filter. I personally don't like this way of filtering when there are better solutions (I.e. Item-based filtering)*

And last, the scalability issue. Because (Hopefully) the app will become a huge success, it's going to be very heavy on the performance to calculate these correlations for each user.

Because of these issues I have decided to do some research on an item-based filter. I just would like some feedback to be sure my recommendations will be correct and to be sure I understand how this works fully.

First, you'll have to calculate a similarity correlation between restaurants, based on reviews left on said restaurants.

Example of a matrix (If I'm correct) where R1 = restaurant 1, etc.

```
   |  R1  |  R2  |  R3  |  R4  |
R1 |  1   | 0.75 | 0.64 | 0.23 |
R2 | 0.75 |  1   | 0.45 | 0.98 |
R3 | 0.64 | 0.45 |  1   | 0.36 |
R4 | 0.23 | 0.98 | 0.36 |  1   |
```

To generate recommendations for a user, you'll have to create a list of restaurants the user has reviewed positively.
Then check the matrix to see which restaurants are similar to these restaurants.
After this, you will have to check which of these restaurants the user hasn't reviewed yet. These will be recommendations for the user.

Using the item-based filter will solve most issues you'll encounter when using the user-based filter.

1. Data sparsity. Because you don't rely on similar users anymore, you won't have the problem of 'Not enough reviews'.
2. Cold start problem. Because you can base your recommendations on 1 review of the user, you won't have the cold start issues (Apart from having null data about the user)
3. Scalability. You don't have to generate the similarity matrix a lot. You can do this once a day or even week. And for generating the recommendations, you can simply consult the matrix and retrieve restaurants from that.

**Now my questions:**

*I would really like some opinions. I'm not saying any of my research are facts, I'm just wondering if I'm doing things correctly.*

Am I doing everything correctly? I have done plenty of research, but since every scenario is different, I find it difficult to determine if I'm doing the right thing.

Is it true that an item-based filter is much better than an user-based one?

How exactly would you calculate a similarity between restaurants? I understand the angle between vectors, but how do you determine the points on the vectors? You can't just take reviews and put them against other reviews, since then all highest rated restaurants will be very similar. How do you set up these vectors?

In my scenario, what would be the best solution, and what similarity coefficient would be best?

Also, what would happen when my review matrix looks like this?

```
       |  R1  |  R2  | 
User 1 |  ?   |  5   | 
User 2 |  ?   |  3   | 
User 3 |  5   |  ?   |  
User 4 |  3   |  ?   |
```

Is it possible to calculate a similarity between these two restaurants? And if not, how could I fix that?

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated!